# Spring Database Integration Test, when to flush or?

Tags: spring, hibernate, integration-testing

I am fairly new to spring, and doing some integration tests. 
Using Hibernate, MySql and Spring data JPA.
I am using transaction support and everything gets rolled back at the end of each test.

For example:

```
@Test (expected=DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
public void findAndDelete() {
    UUID uuid = UUID.fromString(TESTID);
    User user= iUserService.findOne(uuid);
    iUserService.delete(cashBox);

    iUserService.flush();                

    assertNull(iUserService.findOne(uuid));
}
```

In the above code, I call the iUserService.flush(), so that the sql gets sent to the DB, and an expected DataIntegrityViolationException occurs because there is a foreign key from User to another table (Cascade is not allowed, None). All good so far.

Now, if I remove the iUserService.flush()
then the expected exception does not occur because the sql does not get sent to the DB.

I tried adding the flush() into a teardown @After method, but that didn't work as the test does not see the exception outside of the test method.

Is there any way to avoid calling the flush within the test methods?

It would be preferable if the developers on my team did not have to use the flush method at all in their testing code

Edit:
I tried adding the following

```
    @Before
public void before() {
    Session session = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager().unwrap(Session.class);
    session.setFlushMode(FlushMode.ALWAYS);

}
```

but it does seem to flush the sqls, before each query.

Answer (score 1):

In my humble opinion, it's better than the developers of your team know what they are doing.

It includes the things that are configured by default and the consequences of that.

Please, take a look to why you need [avoid false positives when testing ORM code](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-tx-false-positives)